# Wildfly digest login-config with database login module

Tags: java, encryption, jaas, wildfly-8

I try to encrypt password in database login module with Wildfly picketbox module. These are my sources.

== web.xml

```
 ... 
 <security-role> 
    <role-name>administrator</role-name> 
 </security-role> 

 <login-config> 
    <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method> 
    <realm-name>WildFly8DigestRealm</realm-name> 
 </login-config> 
 ....
```

== jboss-web.xml

```
 ... 
 <jboss-web> 
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/my_secure_domain</security-domain> 
 </jboss-web>
```

== standalone.xml

```
... 
 <security-domain name="my_secure_domain" cache-type="default"> 
    <authentication> 
       <login-module code="Database" flag="required"> 
          <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS"/> 
          <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from credential where uid=?"/> 
          <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select urole, 'Roles' from credential where uid=?"/> 
          <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/> 
          <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/> 
          <module-option name="hashUserPassword" value="true"/> 
          <module-option name="hashStorePassword" value="true"/> 
       </login-module> 
    </authentication> 
 </security-domain>
```

Password is encrypted with below

== EncryptPassword.java

```
import java.security.MessageDigest; 
import org.jboss.security.Base64Encoder; 

public class EncryptPassword { 

  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    String algoritmo = "MD5"; 
    String clearTextPassword = "passwd123"; 
    String hashedPassword = null; 

    try { 
       byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance(algoritmo).digest(clearTextPassword.getBytes()); 
       hashedPassword = Base64Encoder.encode(hash); 
       System.out.println("Clear Text Password : " + clearTextPassword); 
       System.out.println("Encrypted Password : " + hashedPassword); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
  } 
 }
```

And also I executed Java command on shell like below as well as above Java file:

C:>java -cp c:\wildfly-8.0.0.final\modules\system\layers\base\org\picketbox\main\picketbox-4.0.20.Final.jar org.jboss.security.Base64Encoder passwd123 MD5

Both result brings the same hashed password and hashed password is updated.

```
Clear Text Password : passwd123 
Encrypted Password : EWT55bjO92g5bc1TdOS26w==
```

However, login is still failed. And in server.log it throws the following exception.

```
 LoginModule Class: org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule 
 ControlFlag: LoginModuleControlFlag: required 
 Options: 
 name=hashUserPassword, value=true 
 name=hashAlgorithm, value=MD5 
 name=principalsQuery, value=select password from credential where uid=? 
 name=hashEncoding, value=base64 
 name=dsJndiName, value=java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS 
 name=hashStorePassword, value=true 
 name=rolesQuery, value=select urole, 'Roles' from credential where uid=? 

 2014-07-15 21:06:45,845 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000236: Begin initialize method 
 2014-07-15 21:06:45,845 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000281: Password hashing activated, algorithm: MD5, encoding: base64, charset: null, callback: null, storeCallBack: null 
 2014-07-15 21:06:45,846 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000262: Module options [dsJndiName: java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS, principalsQuery: select password from credential where uid=?, rolesQuery: select urole, 'Roles' from credential where uid=?, suspendResume: true] 
 2014-07-15 21:06:45,847 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000240: Begin login method 
 2014-07-15 21:06:46,022 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000263: Executing query select password from credential where uid=? with username admin 
 2014-07-15 21:06:46,037 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000283: Bad password for username admin 
 2014-07-15 21:06:46,037 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000244: Begin abort method 
 2014-07-15 21:06:46,037 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX000206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX000070: Password invalid/Password required 
 at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:284) [picketbox-4.0.20.Final.jar:4.0.20.Final] 
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60] 
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60] 
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60] 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60] 
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60] 
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60] 
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60] 
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60] 
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60] 
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60] 
 at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
```

Comment: byte[] hash = MessageDigest.getInstance(algoritmo).digest(clearTextPassword.getBytes()); 
    hashedPassword = Base64Encoder.encode(hash);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.picketbox/picketbox/4.0.20.Final/org/jboss/security/auth/spi/UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java?av=f), I see the following happening:

- The input user password is hashed/encoded because `hashUserPassword` is set to `true` and the algorithm and encoding are provided.
- The password retrieved from the database is hashed/encoded because `hashStorePassword` is set to `true` and the algorithm and encoding are provided.
- The two hashed/encoded passwords are compared.

Now, if your database already contains the hashed/encoded password (which I assume), this means that the one retrieved from the database will be doubly hashed/encoded, and the comparison with the user-provided one will fail.

The solution would then be to change the `hashStorePassword` option to `false` like this:

```
<module-option name="hashStorePassword" value="false"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I changed the value of hashStorePassword to false. But I am afraid it did not work. Login failed and same exception logging.Even I changed the values of both hashUserPassword and hashStorePassword to false but the source threw the same results.

Comment: Can you confirm that your database does contain the correctly hashed/encoded value, and that the column that stores the password is not of type `CHAR`?

Comment: The type of password column is VARCHAR(64). But i think my hashed password is wrong itself, not correctly encrypted.The plain password login in BASIC login-config is successful. Only in DIGEST login-config with database login module and even with UsersRoles login module. I am afraid my password encryption source and config seem to be totally wrong!!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the line `module-option name="hashUserPassword" value="true"` and change line `module-option name="hashStorePassword" value="true"` to `module-option name="hashStorePassword" value="false"`  because you have already hashed your password.